# What are the differences among flat address space,linear addresses,base address,effective address calculations

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, memory-address, addressing-mode, memory-segmentation

What are the differences among all these things : flat addresses ,base
address , linear addresses , effective addresses, physical address , effective address calculations ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

80x86 has both segmentation and paging; where virtual addresses (that software use) are converted into physical addresses (that hardware like memory controller) uses. For the full conversion:

- first CPU determines the **effective address/offset** (e.g. for an instruction like "`mov eax,[eax+ebx*4+99]`" the CPU calculates the result of "eax+ebx*4+99")
- then the CPU applies segmentation (by adding **segment base address**, after checking segment limit) to get a **linear address**.
- then the CPU uses the linear address and page tables (and/or TLBs) to convert the linear address into a **physical address**.

Note: If the segment base addresses are all always zero (and segment limits are set to max.), then segmentation is effectively disabled (because it does nothing). This is often called "**flat addressing**" (and is what most operating systems do).

Comment: In case it's not obvious: if paging is disabled then linear addresses already *are* physical addresses.  But yes, with paging enabled, it happens after segmentation.  Segmentation does not enable using more than 4GiB of memory in a single process's virtual address-space; linear address-space is only 32-bit in 32-bit mode.  (64-bit in 64-bit mode.)